# Calculate Error Rates from Gold Standard Dataframe

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a dataframe with 4 columns as shown below. Each row represents classification or regression results for a particular dataset (with a specific parameter setting). I have another dataframe with the gold standard results (Kappa and Accuracy for classification, and R-squared and RMSE for regression) for each dataset. I would like to generate a dataframe with two new columns in addition to the existing ones showing the errors for these two metrics respectively.

That is, I would like to, for each row in the first (sample) dataframe, find the difference between Metric 1 in the gold standard dataframe and Metric 1 in the sample dataframe. The same applies to Metric 2. New columns could be named Error 1 and Error 2. Matching the dataset in each row (in the sample dataframe) with the dataset in the gold standard dataframe.

Sample Dataframe:

```
Dataset, Metric_1, Metric_2, ML_Type
ccp, 11.8076142844202, 0.628949889120101, regression
pageblocks, 0.968940316686967, 0.84426843805383, classification
onp, 0.65282098713529, 0.305364681866831, classification
pageblocks, 0.961023142509135, 0.795966628677049, classification
concrete, 10.4831489351907, 0.62767229736877, regression
onp, 0.650802993357437, 0.301621021444335, classification
concrete, 10.8875688078687, 0.599691053769861, regression
ccp, 4.60154386445267, 0.927419750011992, regression
```

Gold Standard Dataframe:

```
Dataset, Metric_1, Metric_2, ML_Type
ccp, 4.52997493965786, 0.929612792495658, regression
pageblocks, 0.971376370280146, 0.853898273639253, classification
onp, 0.66476078365425, 0.329343309931143, classification
concrete, 9.98998588557546, 0.598660395228019, regression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the error for each type of model, the following will work:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
    ~Dataset, ~Metric_1, ~Metric_2, ~ML_Type,
    "ccp", 11.8076142844202, 0.628949889120101, "regression", 
    "pageblocks", 0.968940316686967, 0.84426843805383, "classification", 
    "onp", 0.65282098713529, 0.305364681866831, "classification", 
    "pageblocks", 0.961023142509135, 0.795966628677049, "classification", 
    "concrete", 10.4831489351907, 0.62767229736877, "regression", 
    "onp", 0.650802993357437, 0.301621021444335, "classification", 
    "concrete", 10.8875688078687, 0.599691053769861, "regression", 
    "ccp", 4.60154386445267, 0.927419750011992, "regression" 
)

gold <- tribble(
    ~Dataset, ~Metric_1, ~Metric_2, ~ML_Type,
    "ccp", 4.52997493965786, 0.929612792495658, "regression", 
    "pageblocks", 0.971376370280146, 0.853898273639253, "classification", 
    "onp", 0.66476078365425, 0.329343309931143, "classification", 
    "concrete", 9.98998588557546, 0.598660395228019, "regression"
)

err <- gold %>%
    rename_with(~paste0(., "_gold"), .cols = -Dataset) %>%
    right_join(df, by = "Dataset") %>%
    mutate(
        Metric_1_err = Metric_1 - Metric_1_gold,
        Metric_2_err = Metric_2 - Metric_2_gold
    )
select(err, -ends_with("gold"))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  Dataset    Metric_1 Metric_2 ML_Type        Metric_1_err Metric_2_err
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>        <dbl>
1 ccp          11.8      0.629 regression          7.28        -0.301  
2 ccp           4.60     0.927 regression          0.0716      -0.00219
3 pageblocks    0.969    0.844 classification     -0.00244     -0.00963
4 pageblocks    0.961    0.796 classification     -0.0104      -0.0579 
5 onp           0.653    0.305 classification     -0.0119      -0.0240 
6 onp           0.651    0.302 classification     -0.0140      -0.0277 
7 concrete     10.5      0.628 regression          0.493        0.0290 
8 concrete     10.9      0.600 regression          0.898        0.00103
```